# Getting data by search filter from associated models

Tags: cakephp

i have an question regarding search filter in cakephp. Without complicating my question, below are the structure of what i want....

1) I have a projects table.

2) another one is `project_funder_names` table which is associated with `projects` table. `project_id` is in `project_funder_names` table. i have made `project_funder_names` table because i need multiple funder names for a single project, thats why i have made this table.

3) now the main point is i want if i search multiple funders in search filter which is coming in dropdown with checkbox, i will get project details according to these values. so how it would happen.

here is my cakephp find all query....

```
$project_info = $this->Project->find('all', array(
'conditions' =>
     array(
         'Project.status' => 1,
         'OR' => array($search)),
         'fields' => array('id', 'title', 'short_description', 'budget_allocation', 'currency', 'total_comments', 'published_date'),
         'contain' => array(
               'ProjectFunderName' => array(
                   'conditions' => array($search_funder)),
               'Currency' => array('currency_symbol'),
               'ProjectBookmark' => array('project_id', 'user_id')
          )
    )
);
```

problem is in `$search_funder`.

please help me for this.. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to search results based on associated models. One drawback of using containable behavior is if you're trying to assign a condition to an associated model, the main model will be retrieved no matter what.

In situations where you'd want to retrieve the main as well as the associated records based on a condition for the associated model, I'd suggest you to use join.

```
$joins = array(
  array('table' => 'project_funder_names',
    'alias' => 'ProjectFunderName',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'conditions' => array('ProjectFunderName.project_id = Project.id')
   ),
   array('table' => 'currencies',
    'alias' => 'Currency',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    // It's unclear how currencies is associated with the other tables. Use appropriate table join condition here
   ),
   array('table' => 'project_bookmarks',
    'alias' => 'ProjectBookmark',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
     'conditions' => array('ProjectBookmark.project_id = Project.id')
   )
 )
);

$project_info = $this->Project->find('all', 
     array(
       "joins" => $joins,
       "fields" => array(.........)  // Specify all your desired fields here
       "conditions" => array(....)  // Specify all conditions for Project, ProjectFunderName models.
      )
 );
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD